Is it possible to create a null CGPath on iOS?
CGRect has a very convenient built-in constant: CGRect.null
let aRect = ... //get rect from somewhere
CGRect.null.union(aRect) //is aRect
CGRect.null.intersection(aRect) //is CGRect.null

CGPath doesn't have anything like this, meaning you can't do something like:
let bunchOfPaths = [...] //array of CGPaths
let unionPath = bunchOfPaths.reduce(CGPath.null, { $0.union($1) }) //union of all the paths

Nor can you use CGRect.null to create the equivalent:
let nullRectPath = CGPath(rect: .null, transform: nil)
nullRectPath.isEmpty //false (?!)
let zeroRectPath = CGPath(rect: .zero, transform: nil)
nullRectPath.union(zeroRectPath) == zeroRectPath //false

Creating an empty path isn't helpful either:
let emptyPath = zeroRectPath.subtracting(zeroRectPath)
emptyPath.isEmpty //true
emptyPath.union(zeroRectPath) == zeroRectPath //false (!!)

Does a CGPath with the properties described (its union with any CGPath is the other path, its intersection with any CGPath is itself) exist, and if so, how can it be created?

The problem you're facing is that CGPath's == does not mean "contains the same points." It means "contains the same drawing instructions in the same order." And union(using:) does not promise to preserve the order of the drawing instructions. It can't, since it has a fill rule. It's not just appending two paths; it's merging them.
You can see this by printing out the contents:
let rect1 = CGPath(rect: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)), 
                   transform: nil)

dump(rect1, name: "rect1")
=>
- rect1: Path 0x600002c04680:
  moveto (0, 0)
    lineto (100, 0)
    lineto (100, 100)
    lineto (0, 100)
    closepath

dump(CGMutablePath().union(rect1, using: .evenOdd), name: "union")
=>
- union: Path 0x6000030054d0:
  moveto (100, 100)
    lineto (0, 100)
    lineto (0, 0)
    lineto (100, 0)
    closepath

These are not "equal." The tool you want here is .addPath.
let added = CGMutablePath()
added.addPath(rect1)
dump(added, name: "added")
=>
- added: Path 0x600003001680:
  moveto (0, 0)
    lineto (100, 0)
    lineto (100, 100)
    lineto (0, 100)
    closepath

added == rect1    // true

Now this is a bit annoying for your use case, but you can clean it up:
extension CGPath {
    static var zero: CGPath { CGMutablePath() }
    func appending(_ path: CGPath) -> CGPath {
        var copy = self.mutableCopy() ?? CGMutablePath()
        copy.addPath(path)
        return copy
    }

    // Maybe this operator is controversial, but I don't think so. Union is not 
    // sensibly an "add" operation given its fill rule semantics. CGPath
    // is best thought of as a Collection of CGPathElements, and Swift
    // consistently appends Collections using +, even though it's not commutative.
    static func + (lhs: CGPath, rhs: CGPath) -> CGPath {
        lhs.appending(rhs)
    }
}

let bunchOfPaths = [rect1]
let unionPath = bunchOfPaths.reduce(.zero, +)
unionPath == rect1    // true


Instead of CGPath, use CGMutablePath:
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.isEmpty // true


Note that your .null is different from .zero — .zero is a zero size rect, but .null is not even a rect, it's invalid. That's why you couldn't usefully make a path with that rect.

That makes sense, but the mutable path, while empty, still doesn't have the properties I want: CGMutablePath().union(CGPath(rect: .zero, transform: nil)) == CGPath(rect: .zero, transform: nil) //false!!

Yes, that's true, it's still a path.
